# Is tofu considered a processed food?

Tags: tofu

One might not think of tofu as a processed food, but it seems to follow the definition found [here](http://www.foodinsight.org/LinkClick.aspx?fileticket=wtg018sd8qk=&tabid=1398):

> Food processing is any deliberate change in a food that occurs before it's available for us to eat.

Is tofu considered a processed food? If so, in the 'continuum' chart, which would tofu fall under?

Comment: Clearly tofu is processed by that definition. The only food I can think of that is not processed by that definition is a mother's breast milk when consumed directly from the nursing mother. All other food is processed in _some_ way. What question are you really wanting answered?

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with the scope of this site, as defined in the [faq], unless you're asking how it's made. In particular, if you're thinking about nutritional characteristics of processed and unprocessed foods, that is most definitely off-topic.

Comment: I kind of agree with @Jefromi - who cares whether or not some food is technically considered "processed"? Technically anything that's been cooked has been processed, which is almost everything on this site.

Comment: I think the answer here is "yes, but who cares?"

Comment: @Flimzy, breast milk is also processed, by the mamary glands. I think what jdev might have meant was is tofu chemically engineered or altered.

Comment: @Jefromi, he is asking how it's made in a sense, so this question does fall into the scope of the site. and @ Aaronut, it does matter whether or not a food is engineered to a lot of people who about what their food tastes like and the quality of their food.

Comment: @Avien: If he had asked how it's made, then I wouldn't have voted to close it, and he could have edited it - he seemed to have some idea, though, given that he said it fit a definition he found.

Comment: @Avien: Every form of cooking is "chemical engineering and alteration."  I don't think mammory-gland-secretion is considered "processing" by any meaningful definition within food science, nor is photosynthesis.  Perhaps within biology it is, but that's an entirely different realm.

Comment: Reason to suggest reopen: The definitions of primary/secondary/tertiary processed food seem to be well established, and can be used to answer this constructively.

Answer (score 3):

We are being bombarded with the message to eat less 'processed food' so asking what that might mean and which foods it includes is relevant.

Most of us will agree on the definition found here:
www.getting-started-with-healthy-eating.com/processed-food
Processed food refers to the products of food manufacturers; these products are literally manufactured in industrial processes.

Industrial is the key word. I can grind flour at home and bake bread but not with a mixer of 500rpm and 100 additives.

Any site with a more inclusive, favorable definition of 'processed food' is probably an industry representative

My opinion puts tofu at the same processing level as home curd cheese.

Comment: great answer, don't know why you were downvoted.

Answer (score 2):

According to your definition, [tofu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tofu) is a processed food:

> Tofu, also called bean curd, is a food made by coagulating soy milk and then pressing the resulting curds into soft white blocks